# Parsing a JSON based on a condition in SQL Server

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, parsing

This is the JSON definition that is going to be provided (just a short example) and the code that I have implemented to get the expected result:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)

set @json = '{
   "testJson":{
      "testID":"Test1",
      "Value":[
         {
            "Value1":"",
            "Value2":"",
            "Value3":"",
            "Type": "1A"
         },
         {
            "Value1":"123",
            "Value2":"456",         
            "Value3":"Automatic",
            "Type": "2A"
         },
         {
            "Value1":"789",
            "Value2":"159",         
            "Value3":"Manual",
            "Value4":"Success"  ,
            "Type": "3A"
         }
      ]
   }
}'


select 
    'ValueFields' as groupDef,
    -- b.[key],
    -- c.[key],
    STRING_AGG( c.value , ' | ') as val
from 
    openjson(@json, '$.testJson.Value') as b
cross apply 
    openjson(b.value) as c
where 
    b.[key] not in (select b.[key]
                    from openjson(@json, '$.testJson.Value') as b
                    where b.value like ('%1A%'))
```

As you can see each element in the array can have different quantity of attributes (value1,.., value4..), and I only need to consider those elements where the type attribute is not equal to "1A". The query gives me the result requested, however, I am wondering how can I improve the performance of the code given that I'm using the like operator in the sub select, and obviously the original JSON file could a considerable number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
select b.Value --,c.value
from 
openjson(@json, '$.testJson.Value')
with
(
  Value nvarchar(max) '$' as json,
  Type varchar(100) '$.Type'
) as b
--cross apply  openjson(b.Value) as c
where b.Type <> '1A'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    'ValueFields' as groupDef,
    J.value as val
FROM
OPENJSON(@json,'$.testJson.Value') J
WHERE
    JSON_VALUE([value],'$.Type') <> '1A'
```

Comment: Thank you Ross, your solution gave an idea for another json that I need to parse.